# Why there is too much pressure to close the pressure cooker?

Tags: pressure, water, home-experiment

I noticed an interesting behaviour that I cannot find intuitive behaviour.

I use an electric pressure cooker with timer (InstantPot). After some time the heating is disconnected and I can vent.

I noticed that after I vent the cooker and take the items out if I try to close the lid, even after some time, it is locked. That is - pressure detector which prevents opening/closing the lid when there is pressure differential between inside and outside is locking. I need to wait a bit till the pressure equalizes by venting before I finish closing the lid.

I cannot figure why this happens. Water seems to be cool enough to not have fast enough evaporation to prevent locking and normally air is compressible enough for it not to be a problem.

Comment: It is unclear to me what is involved in "try to close the lid".  Some hardware may have safety interlocks that trigger in some situations rather than it being purely a pressure issue.

Comment: A lot more detail is needed before anyone can answer.  Did you operate the pressure cooker at cooking temperature, remove it from its heat source, let it cool down, and then open the lid before trying to close it again?  Are there any "interlocks" on the pressure cooker that lock due to temperature rather than pressure?  What brand name and model of pressure cooker are you using, and what does it look like?

Comment: @BowlOfRed sorry I wasn't clear enough. Yes - I meant the interlock rather than pure pressure.